# Where can I upload jQuery files?

Tags: jquery, web-hosting

I made a website that includes jQuery files, but I just found out that my university's server does not support them. Is there a place where I can upload those files and link them?

Comment: What do you mean your university's server does not support them?

Comment: Are they really big? You can include the jQuery script from Google's CDN and just include your JS scripts on the body of your page.

Comment: The only way that your server could not support them is if when your server is not a webserver...

Comment: They're small: nivo slider, tabs and such. The problem is that they're custom files, not the ones I can link from Google. Also, sorry if the question is stupid, I'm a newbie and I feel a little lost :\

Comment: And now I feel stupid. It didn't work because I had linked the js wrong. Thank you everyone for your suggestions about Google, I will do that :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't. Instead, use the CDNs on [this page](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery).

- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
- http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
- http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Using CDNs will give you the best speed for your jQuery files because chances are that your visitors will already have them cached.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a content-delivery-network. There is an internet company you might have heard of doing it for you :

http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery

this also means most people will have them cached and thus improve your sites responsiveness.

Answer (score 2):

Use the CDN-hosted jQuery files.  You'll get the added bonus that most folks will have them cached already.

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

More URLs here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You could also sign-up or use Tumblr and host your files here: http://www.tumblr.com/themes/upload_static_file

Comment: As a note - Wasn't sure if he meant the actual library or individual files. For the actual library then use one of the above mentioned CDNs.

Comment: I didn't know tumblr did that! So, can I just upload custom js files such as nivo slider and link them?

Comment: @user1308479 Yup. I've used it for a few websites. You could also use Dropbox's public folder.

Answer (score 0):

Google hosts JQuery library for you. You just need to link to it.